# Virtual Keyboard not opening in Unity3D with Steam/MRTK

Tags: unity-game-engine, keyboard, virtual-reality, mrtk

I'm developing with Unity using the MRTK (if that matters) and my project setup is using "PC,Mac &Linux Stand Alone", my player settings are set to enable VR.

I'm copying and pasting directly the code from Unity to open the keyboard, and that function is the first one I call when opening the scene, and yet I can't see it. Is there anything wrong/buggy with it?

I even tried it on a completely empty project. Nothing happens.

Directly from Microsoft:

```
public TouchScreenKeyboard keyboard;

private void Start()
{
OpenSystemKeyboard();
}


public void OpenSystemKeyboard()
{
    keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default, false, false, false, false);
}

No error message, no console message, just nothing....
```

Answer (score 0):

The API in question I believe is only documented to work for the following platforms:

iOS
Android
Windows Store Apps (AKA UWP apps AKA Universal Windows Platform apps)

Since the build process is uses PC/Mac/Linux, it's not a WSA/UWP app, so I wouldn't expect that to show up given Unity's documentation here:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard.html

The older version of the MRTK (HTK) had a keyboard prefab that could be used, though note that that branch is fairly old at this point:

https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/htk_release/Assets/HoloToolkit/UX/Prefabs/Keyboard.prefab

Comment: Yes, however this code I put up there is part of the newest version of the MRTK and also on Microsoft's website, for e.g. here: https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/mrtk_release/Documentation/README_SystemKeyboard.md  This is why I assumed it would work also on Mixed Reality?

Comment: Well, I've had it. I've developed my own, very full proof working on all environments. Will put it in the Unity Asset Store, watch for it, it will be free.